# Git equivalent of RCS co -p?

Tags: git

Is there a `git` equivalent to the old RCS `co -p`?  That command is an option of the "checkout" command `co`, but it didn't really check anything out; it would simply get the requested version of the file and dump it to standard output.  It's something I used a *lot* with RCS (usually redirecting standard output to a file in some other directory that didn't impact my working area).  I looked through the `git` man pages but couldn't find something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many, but the convenient-est one (for me) is `git show`.  Let's say you want to see what file `dir/foo` looked like 3 versions ago in branch `X`:

```
git show X~3:dir/foo
```

You can use `HEAD~n` to back up *`n`* commits in the current branch (and omit the tilde and number entirely to get the most recently checked-in version), etc; see `git rev-parse --help` for specifying revisions.

Comment: Thanks, this works.  I had looked over the man page for `git show`, and it said "For plain blobs, it shows the plain contents", but I didn't think it was what I wanted.  Is a file considered a "blob"?

Comment: Yeah, a file is a "blob". I suspect this lingo is a loan from the database term "binary large object".